# How do I use regex within a certain cell in a csv to edit?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, csv

I have a CSV with a structure as:

Test CSV:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| abc-dfcv | rebtgsergbsedrfgesrg |
|  | water rdfe egreg |
|  | oluiuilegregreg |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| def fefd | rtjtyujdtgfhndgfhjfh |
|  | water edgregerg |

Result needed:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| abc-dfcv | water rdfe egreg |
|  |  |
| def fefd | water edgregerg |

As can be seen, in each cell of column B there are multiple lines. I need to edit it so only the lines which start with "water" are kept within the cell, rest of the lines are omitted. This has to be done for all cells in Column B.

The regex statement I've made is `re.findall("^water'.*")`.

I tried to directly apply regex, but it halts and errors at the end of a line within a cell.

Thinking of something along these lines, but blanking on what the regex input should be.

```
df = pd.read_csv("MyFile.csv")

for p in range(len(df.index)):
   df._set_value(p, "SCHEDULES", str(re.findall("^water'.*", ??????????????? )))
df.to_csv("Nexpose_Schedules.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Please show the actual CSV text file, not some sort of astral projection where we have to guess what the actual data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function 'startswith' instead of regex and the answer would like this:

```
result = df[df["Column B"].str.startswith("water")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('MyFile.csv')
df_new = df.loc[df['Column B'].str.contains(r'\bwater', case=False)]
```